# from the book "Python Crash Course", why does the author write '--snip--'?

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering this and maybe some of you have read this book. I am guessing he writes it to remove the code but when I do, I more often than not get a syntax error.

Thank you.

Comment: oh sorry, and to make things more clear i am on the alien invasion project, that starts at page 240 or so

Comment: I'm the author of PCC. The answer below is correct, I just wanted to add that you can see the full code for the project at each stage [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_12). There's a snapshot of the project as it exists at the end of each main section in each chapter.

Comment: Thank you for responding Eric, and thank you for the link!

Comment: @xhienne Thanks, I edited the question to remove the link. When you make a comment about something like that, you might not want to add your own link to the site in your comment. :)

Comment: @japhyr My link was not a direct link to the book but anyway I removed my comment. For the link to disappear, your edit still needs someone else to approve it. I have asked moderators to make the link disappear from the edit history as well, but I don't know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an instruction to remove anything, just a way to show "there's more here, I'm just not typing/printing all of it."

For example, page 242 has

```py
# Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
 --snip--
```

But if you look back to 241, you can find

```py
# Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
```

You're meant to understand that `--snip--` represents this bit of code.

Comment: Nobody starts out good at everything, just keep at it!

Comment: Oh well since you've deleted your second comment my response just seems rude.

Comment: no it doesn't thank you for responding though, you were very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In the book, Python Crash course the author used `--snip--` as a placeholder. I am reading the book, in chapter 6: Dictionaries for example;

```
  favorite_languages = {
       --snip--
       }
```

The above `--snip--` requires the key/value pair used previously in the chapter or you can define a different key/value pair.

Comment: Yep, this is such an old question and I just lost 2 rep.

Answer (score 0):

`--snip--` is not Python code. The author of the book probably uses this as a placeholder value for a code *snippet* that you either have to write yourself or is omitted because it is not important at that point.